# Spring Multiple Property Placeholder and SPEL order independent

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have two xml config files using `property-placeholder`. I'm having an issue where the order of the import statements for these two config files will effect SPEL in one of the config files.

**config-a.xml**

```
<context:property-placeholder
            location="classpath:dev/food.properties"
            ignore-unresolvable="true" />

<bean id="foodNames" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map key-type="com.my.project.Food"
            value-type="java.lang.String">
            <entry key="#{T(com.my.project.Food).SUSHI}"
                value="${dynamodb.sushi:#{null}}" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**config-b.xml**

```
<context:property-placeholder
            location="classpath:dev/animals.properties"
            ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

If I import `config-a.xml` before `config-b.xml`, the value is properly set in the `foodNames` map. But if I set `config-b.xml` before `config-a.xml`, the value is `null`. A more visual example can be seen below.

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
// Value is properly set
<import resource="classpath:spring/config-a.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:spring/config-b.xml" />

// Value is null
<import resource="classpath:spring/config-b.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:spring/config-a.xml" />
```

What can I do to make it order independent?

Comment: spring version? are you hitting this bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9989

Comment: Spring 4.1.6, and yeah, that's the bug I'm hitting

Comment: Don't use XML use java config and use `@PropertySource` to declare your files. That way you have a single property-placeholder and still the ability to use multiple property files.

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you possibly show some example code on what it would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (and I suspect recommended approach) is to use java based configuration. In this configuration define a bean for the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and use `@PropertySource` annotations to load your property files.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:dev/food.properties")
public class ConfigA {}

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:dev/animals.properties")
public class ConfigB {}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("your-packages-here")
public class RootConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Something like this. All configuration classes are loaded as well as the property files before a replacement is going to happen.